# Route endpoint is not routing, getting a reference error

Tags: javascript, html, express

My web application, a url shortener, is not routing to the page when check to see if a user is logged in or not.

The route should:
filter the entire list in the urlDatabase by comparing the userID with the logged-in user's ID. And only list urls if the user is logged in.

```
 app.get('/urls', (req, res) => {
  let templateVars = {
    urls: urlsForUser(req.cookies.user_id, urlDatabase),
    user: users[req.cookies.user_id],
  };
  res.render("urls_index", templateVars);
 });
```

when I try to access the endpoint I get

```
< ReferenceError: /vagrant/w3/tinyapp/views/urls_index.ejs:11
    9| </head>
    10| <body>
 >> 11|   <%- include('partials/_header') %>
    12|   <main style="margin: 1em;">
    13|     <h3>My URLs</h3>
    14|     <table class="table">

/vagrant/w3/tinyapp/views/partials/_header.ejs:13
    11|       </div>
    12|     </div>
 >> 13|     <% if(!user_id) { %>
    14|           <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/register" style="background-color: white; margin: 10px">Register</a>                 
    15|           <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/login" style="background-color: white; margin: 10px">Login</a>     
    16|     <% } else { %>

user_id is not defined
    at eval (/vagrant/w3/tinyapp/views/partials/_header.ejs:12:8)
    at _header (/vagrant/w3/tinyapp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:691:17)
    at include (/vagrant/w3/tinyapp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:689:39)
    at eval (/vagrant/w3/tinyapp/views/urls_index.ejs:12:17)
    at urls_index (/vagrant/w3/tinyapp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:691:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/vagrant/w3/tinyapp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/vagrant/w3/tinyapp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (/vagrant/w3/tinyapp/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/vagrant/w3/tinyapp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/vagrant/w3/tinyapp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
```

my header code is:

`````
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-success">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/urls">TinyApp</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/urls">My URLs</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/urls/new">Create New URL</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% if(!user_id) { %>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/register" style="background-color: white; margin: 10px">Register</a>                 
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/login" style="background-color: white; margin: 10px">Login</a>     
    <% } else { %>
      <form class="form-inline" action="/logout" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
          <label for="name"><b>Logged in as <%= user_id["email"] %></b></label>
          <button type="logout" class="btn btn-primary" href="/logout">Logout</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    <% } %>
  </nav>
</header>

````
`````

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `user_id is not defined` which means you have passed  wrong data to the template.

You are passing user instead of user_id in the templateVars.

**Update user as user_id in the templateVars**